# Perforce Importing folders from separate streams to same folder on workspace

Tags: perforce

So i have 2 streams:

//Stream_1/Folder_1/-files-

//Stream_2/Folder_2/-files-

I want to have these locations imported into:
//workspace/Folder/-here-

When I do `import Folder/... //Stream_1/Folder_1/...`

I get only 1 of the streams, it appears to be stomping what is there and replacing it with the other streams files.

Is this just P4 being dumb? Am I missing something....

Answer (score 0):

Perforce mappings are one-to-one (with specific exceptions that are IMO best avoided).  If you want to import two different depot paths into a stream, you need to pick two different stream-relative paths that they will correspond to:

```
import Folder/1/... //Stream_1/Folder_1/...
import Folder/2/... //Stream_2/Folder_2/...
```

You can pick any paths you want, but if they conflict (either fully or partially), the later path will take precedence over the earlier one for whichever parts of the namespace are in conflict.

Comment: A pedantic aside (although it may save you a headache someday) -- the first path in the `import` statement is relative to the current stream, but the second path is interpreted as a *depot path*, not as the stream that it corresponds to.  If the stream includes imports, or if it's virtual, its inherited paths will *not* be included by the import statement.